# how to put wait command in selenium testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, data-driven-tests

When running the below code in TestNG and WebDriver, the testcase is failing. Let me know if the implicit and explicit wait is correctly implemented.

```
public class QCEntry
{
    private WebDriver browser;
    private String baseUrl;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        browser = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.example.org/";
        browser.get(baseUrl);
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        browser.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMain_txtUsername")).clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void testImportexport1() throws Exception
    {
        for (int row = 1; row < s.getRows(); row++)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(browser, 100);
            browser.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphTest_LocationPanel_ddlSiteLevel3")).click();
            wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphTest_LocationPanel_ddlSiteLevel3")));
            browser.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphTest_LocationPanel_ddlSiteLevel3")).sendKeys("Ames");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question :)

Comment: What kind of failures are you getting?  Can you add some more detail to include any exceptions.  It would also help to be able to see at least the rest of the loop, if not the whole test method as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some error info... what error are you getting and where?

Other than that, there's some basic cleanup that I would start with that may help with your error.

1. [Don't mix implicit and explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).
2. Declare locators and reuse them.
3. `wait.until` returns an element. Store or use it directly rather than scraping the page again.
4. You realize you are clicking an element, then waiting for that element to be visible, and then entering text into that same element? Seems strange like maybe you should be interacting with at least a couple different elements instead of just one.

   ```
   public class QCEntry
   {
       private WebDriver browser;
       private String baseUrl;

       @BeforeClass
       public void setUp() throws Exception
       {
           browser = new FirefoxDriver();
           baseUrl = "http://www.example.org/";
           browser.get(baseUrl);
           browser.manage().window().maximize();
           browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           browser.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMain_txtUsername")).clear();
       }

       @Test
       public void testImportexport1() throws Exception
       {
           By somethingLocator = By.id("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphTest_LocationPanel_ddlSiteLevel3");
           for (int row = 1; row < s.getRows(); row++)
           {
               WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(browser, 100);
               browser.findElement(somethingLocator).click();
               wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(somethingLocator)).sendKeys("Ames");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment above requesting more information.  I'll edit this answer once more is available, but I do have an observation on your element interactions.

It appears that you are clicking an element, waiting for it to be visible, then sending keystrokes to it.  I'd recommend utilizing the wait as the initializer of the element, thus waiting before the click and sendkeys.  As well, while your code is technically correct in how your invoking the actions, there is a more efficient way to do it.  The ExpectedConditions methods (at least most of them) return a WebElement, allowing you to perform a wait and initialize an element in one statement.

Try this:

```
WebElement element = wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphTest_LocationPanel_ddlSiteLevel3")));
element.click();
element.sendKeys("Ames");
```

This allows you to only have to define your element ID once (enhancing maintainability), but also incorporates the wait into the element initialization.  Then, it's just as simple as using the element to invoke the commands.

I'd like to see the error(s) that you are getting, but your invoking the wait *after* the click doesn't seem to make much sense.  I'll edit this once you add some new detail to your question.